# Android: NullPointerException, ArrayList, Initialized, Compatible Types

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Running into a really strange thing here. I have an array list, that is initialized to the proper object class. I create an instance of that class. When I call the ArrayList.add method(s), I get a non-catchable NullPointerException. (I put it alone in between a try/catch, and still it doesn't work).

IDE: Eclipse; developing an android app. Here's sample code:

```
ArrayList<ClassName> items = new ArrayList<ClassName>();
ClassName item = new ClassName();
items.add(item);
-- or --
items.add(0, item);
```

I've isolated that this is the *only* line of code that is throwing the non-catchable NullPointerException. Furthermore, there is no "caused by" line showing up in the stack trace; it just jumps to NullPointerException after outputting a process ID with my package name.

Is there a known bug in Android with handling NullPointerExceptions?

Also, of note, though it crashed the activity from view, it can still run in the background. I've inspected the XML files and put them as bare as I can.

Cleaning the project didn't help, either.

EDIT: (added stack trace):

```
08-17 13:41:51.200: D/jdwp(4000): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
08-17 13:41:51.200: D/dalvikvm(4000): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-17 13:41:51.210: D/dalvikvm(4026): Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-17 13:41:51.210: I/ActivityManager(752): Start proc com.example.packagename for activity com.example.packagename/.MainActivity: pid=4026 uid=10081 gids={50081}
08-17 13:41:51.220: I/MicrophoneInputStream(1457): mic_close fib@42ef1210
08-17 13:41:51.290: I/HotwordRecognitionRnr(1457): Stopping hotword detection.
08-17 13:41:51.290: I/HotwordRecognitionRnr(1457): Hotword detection finished
08-17 13:41:51.300: I/System.out(4026): addItem: this.items [], 0
08-17 13:41:51.300: I/System.out(4026): addItem: item com.example.packagename.ClassName@42eee1c8
08-17 13:41:51.330: I/Adreno-EGL(4026): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
08-17 13:41:51.360: D/OpenGLRenderer(4026): Enabling debug mode 0
08-17 13:41:51.360: D/AndroidRuntime(4026): Shutting down VM
08-17 13:41:51.360: W/dalvikvm(4026): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e53ba8)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026): Process: com.example.packagename, PID: 4026
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2277)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-17 13:41:51.370: E/AndroidRuntime(4026):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 13:41:51.370: W/ActivityManager(752):   Force finishing activity com.example.packagename/.MainActivity
08-17 13:41:51.460: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 35K, 11% free 28977K/32548K, paused 75ms, total 76ms
08-17 13:41:51.460: I/dalvikvm-heap(752): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.148MB for 856096-byte allocation
08-17 13:41:51.520: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 11% free 29808K/33388K, paused 62ms, total 62ms
08-17 13:41:51.580: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 11% free 29790K/33388K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
08-17 13:41:51.580: I/dalvikvm-heap(752): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.943MB for 856096-byte allocation
08-17 13:41:51.630: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 30626K/34228K, paused 55ms, total 55ms
08-17 13:41:52.130: W/ActivityManager(752): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{43658008 u0 com.example.packagename/.MainActivity t307 f}
08-17 13:41:53.210: I/Process(4026): Sending signal. PID: 4026 SIG: 9
08-17 13:41:53.220: D/audio_hw_primary(185): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
08-17 13:41:53.220: W/InputMethodManagerService(752): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@435a0348 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@4379e598
08-17 13:41:53.230: I/ActivityManager(752): Process com.example.packagename (pid 4026) has died.
08-17 13:41:53.230: I/WindowState(752): WIN DEATH: Window{436cd958 u0 com.example.packagename/com.example.packagename.MainActivity}
08-17 13:41:53.270: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 931K, 9% free 18786K/20452K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-17 13:41:53.280: I/MicrophoneInputStream(1457): mic_starting fib@43141e90
08-17 13:41:53.290: I/HotwordRecognitionRnr(1457): Starting hotword detection.
08-17 13:41:53.300: D/audio_hw_primary(185): select_devices: out_snd_device(0: ) in_snd_device(35: voice-rec-mic)
08-17 13:41:53.300: D/(185): Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000003E 
08-17 13:41:53.300: E/ACDB-LOADER(185): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
08-17 13:41:53.300: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 5% free 19468K/20452K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 28ms
08-17 13:41:53.380: I/HotwordWorker(1457): onReady
08-17 13:41:54.040: I/ActivityManager(752): START u0 {act=com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity} from pid 862
08-17 13:41:54.090: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 914K, 13% free 29849K/34228K, paused 52ms, total 52ms
08-17 13:41:54.100: I/MicrophoneInputStream(1457): mic_close fib@43141e90
08-17 13:41:54.140: I/HotwordRecognitionRnr(1457): Hotword detection finished
08-17 13:41:54.140: I/HotwordRecognitionRnr(1457): Stopping hotword detection.
08-17 13:41:54.170: I/ActivityManager(752): Displayed com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity: +77ms
08-17 13:41:54.970: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1035K, 14% free 29688K/34216K, paused 66ms, total 66ms
08-17 13:41:55.020: D/dalvikvm(752): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 848K, 14% free 29676K/34216K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
08-17 13:41:55.120: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 734K, 9% free 18782K/20452K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
08-17 13:41:55.130: I/MicrophoneInputStream(1457): mic_starting fib@4314ee00
08-17 13:41:55.130: I/HotwordRecognitionRnr(1457): Starting hotword detection.
08-17 13:41:55.140: D/audio_hw_primary(185): select_devices: out_snd_device(0: ) in_snd_device(35: voice-rec-mic)
08-17 13:41:55.140: D/(185): Failed to fetch the lookup information of the device 0000003E 
08-17 13:41:55.140: E/ACDB-LOADER(185): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
08-17 13:41:55.150: D/dalvikvm(1457): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 5% free 19472K/20452K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 24ms
08-17 13:41:55.220: I/HotwordWorker(1457): onReady
08-17 13:42:05.810: D/Finsky(2105): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace. I strongly suspect that the bug is in some code you haven't shown... it feels *very* unlikely that this is a bug in Android.

Comment: How do you know the NPE is "noncatchable"? (Not that I suggest catching it because it likely indicates an error in your code somewhere.)

Comment: Are you sure that `item` is not null??

Comment: irem being null should be ok.  You can add null to a list.  items being null is an issue.

Comment: I'm certain items is not null; I have an if condition outside of it that checks this, too.

Comment: Seems you're using an Adapter, right? Please post the `getView` then. I suspect it's returning null.

Comment: The view I'm adding is returned correctly. The app gets the NPE when the items.add() method is called.  @JonSkeet I posted the stack trace.

Comment: Well the NPE is in `obtainView`... where does your code come into it?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290104

Comment: @cygery Thanks for pointing that one out. It's strange; that method wasn't being called when I started writing this, and it always returned null. I fixed it, and it now works.